# How can i find the shortest path from any node to a set A

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

I have an un-directed graph 'G' and a set 'A' of nodes in the graph G

I'm struggling with finding an efficient algorithm that finds the the shortest paths from any node in the graph G to the closest node in the set 'A'

I thought about this:  having a minimum distance array to all nodes, Running BFS algorithm on each node in set A and after BFS completion, update the array if a shorter path was found, this time complexity is O(k(n+m)) - which is a lot when as K grows, I was told there is a more efficient algorithm i can use. Please note, I'm only allowed to use BFS algorithm in this exercise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extra node that had edges to every node in 'A.' Run BFS from this extra node. The distance from every node to the closest node in 'A' is 1 less than the distance to this extra node.

Answer (score 0):

You really just need a single pass of your BFS algorithm if you start with  all the nodes from `A` in the initial queue.

- keep track of already visited nodes and their paths to nodes from A in a map/dictionary
- initialize the BFS queue with tuples `(a, empty_path)` for each node `a` in your `A` set
- while there are more elements in the queue, pop the next node and path from the queue
- if the node is already in the `visited` map, skip it
- otherwise, add it to `visited` with the given path
- add neighbor nodes to the queue with extended paths

Example in Python:

```py
# 2--0--1
# |     |
# 3     4
graph = {0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 4], 2: [0, 3], 3: [2], 4: [1]}
A = [2, 0]

import collections
queue = collections.deque([(a, []) for a in A])
visited = {}
while queue:
    cur, path = queue.popleft()
    if cur in visited: continue
    visited[cur] = path
    for node in graph[cur]:
        queue.append((node, [cur] + path))
print(visited)
# {2: [], 0: [], 3: [2], 1: [0], 4: [1, 0]}
```